# What is column 'type' means at Ethereum method eth_getTransactionByHash?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, etherscan

As the title said,
I can't find any document that has a `type` column description,
and don't know the value means.
Is anyone has an idea?

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":1,
    "result":{
        "blockHash":"0xf64a12502afc36db3d29931a2148e5d6ddaa883a2a3c968ca2fb293fa9258c68",
        "blockNumber":"0x70839",
        "from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "gas":"0x30d40",
        "gasPrice":"0xba43b7400",
        "hash":"0x1e2910a262b1008d0616a0beb24c1a491d78771baa54a33e66065e03b1f46bc1",
        "input":"0xfc36e15b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a4861636b65726e65777300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "nonce":"0xa7",
        "to":"0x03fca6077d38dd99d0ce14ba32078bd2cda72d74",
        "transactionIndex":"0x0",
        "value":"0x0",
        "type":"0x0", // <- here
        "v":"0x1c",
        "r":"0xe7ccdba116aa95ae8d9bdd02f619a0cdfc1f60c5740b3899865822a80cd70218",
        "s":"0xf200df1921ea988d16280a0873b69cb782a54e8a596d15e700710c820c8d2a9e"
    }
}
```

And an additional question here,
as an above result, how can I know the transaction has been completed or failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Typed transaction envelope added in the [EIP-2718](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2718). Implementation of this EIP was deployed in April 2021 in the Berlin hardfork ([source](https://www.coindesk.com/berlin-hard-fork-is-now-live-on-ethereum)).

The field allows to use future transaction types without backwards compatibility. An example of a new incompatible tx type (value `0x01`) is in the [EIP-2930](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930), also deployed in the Berlin hardfork.

Probably because it's a new field, it's not yet (June 2021) included in the JSON-RPC [documentation](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactionbyhash). But other documentations, such as [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse), already started covering it.

---

You can get the transaction status (if it succeeded or reverted) from the [transaction receipt](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactionreceipt) field `status`. It's not included in the regular `getTransactionByHash` method used in your question.

Mind that the `status` is not included in pre-Byznatium (October 2017) transactions and can also be missing in some future transaction types.